# BitCoin - how to build raw transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin

According to the list from other question, to build a raw transaction I need:

1. `listunspent` - you get the list of all unspent transactions
2. You determine which ones you want to spend
3. You use `createrawtransaction` to create your inputs / outputs, taking
   txid and vout from the list of transactions that you have that are
   playing, as well as a list of transactions that constitute a "money
   supply" for you.
4. Use `signrawtransaction` to sign the created transaction
5. Use `sendrawtransaction` to send the signed transaction

But there is one big problem - `listunspent` shows unspent amounts that are actually already spent, thus, I will have insufficient funds error in future or negative balance...

E.g.:

Created address 15d8uY8uubNFnn3DXaoGN123ZCRkm3HJK9.
Sent to it 0.01 BTC.
Later sent from this address 0.00400000 with fee 0.00010714:

```
    [
      {
        "account": "login_67",
        "address": "15d8uY8uubNFnn3DXaoGN123ZCRkm3HJK9",
------> "category": "receive",
        "amount": 0.01000000,
        "label": "login_67",
        "vout": 0,
        "confirmations": 628,
        "blockhash": "0000000000000000006bf20ac85a50d3e014a636b51231c78c6b27fe0a8e9223",
        "blockindex": 2,
        "blocktime": 1463753010,
        "txid": "f37679b68c8ee3cd362b5bb15b2d8007af4eab173eee2d6269a132b9491a55ad",
        "walletconflicts": [
        ],
        "time": 1463752690,
        "timereceived": 1463752690,
        "bip125-replaceable": "no"
      },
      {
        "account": "login_67",
        "address": "1BeqRNunznfwuFHnufXLFRhaCDm1mrvMS6",
------> "category": "send",
        "amount": -0.00400000,
        "vout": 1,
        "fee": -0.00010714,
        "confirmations": 609,
        "blockhash": "000000000000000000699cd44c4aed1eeb9c66181f6260bfe41473e66e1ece06",
        "blockindex": 1614,
        "blocktime": 1463767099,
        "txid": "9a39b070d8f21ddf9bd16e641c4b252c2da701336fd36b707ca072fd1ca11d58",
        "walletconflicts": [
        ],
        "time": 1463766747,
        "timereceived": 1463766747,
        "bip125-replaceable": "no",
        "abandoned": false
      }
    ]
```

Getbalance shows correct balance of **0.00589286**

And listunspent shows wrong info about available funds:

```
[
  {
    "txid": "f37679b68c8ee3cd362b5bb15b2d8007af4eab173eee2d6269a132b9491a55ad",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "15d8uY8uubNFnn3DXaoGN123ZCRkm3HJK9",
    "account": "login_67",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a91432b613c311d4c9c72f3ed1ba5e2c1d96645bd2da88ac",
    "amount": 0.01000000,
    "confirmations": 628,
    "spendable": true
  }
]
```

Like there wasn't any send transaction.

So how can I collect up all unspent funds from TXs?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 9):

### **Scenario:**

> Michael receives 0.05000000 BTC from Pablo and another 0.01000000 BTC
>   from Kuradang. Michael also wants to send 0.02500000 BTC to Berteng.
>   Each amount that Michael receives has the corresponding T and other
>   details. Lets check that out using `listunspent` command then create a
>   raw transaction using `createrawtransaction` after that sign it using
>   `signrawtransaction` and send that raw transaction using
>   `sendrawtransaction`.

### **Given:**

- Michael's Bitcoin Address: mkrzDhhZtzQm8zgckSs4fMNrvtNJ66zaFe
- Berteng's Bitcoin Address: mxh3H416KCRoBDiweSESew5YJyAk1nxLrN
- Send to Berteng: 0.02500000 mBTC

### **Step 1)**

`listunspent`

*Format:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli listunspent [misconf=1] [max_number_confirmation=99999999] '''["<wallet_address>"]'''
```

> Lets check Michael's list of unspent using his address.

*Execute:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli listunspent 1 99999999 '''["mkrzDhhZtzQm8zgckSs4fMNrvtNJ66zaFe"]'''
```

*Result:*

```
[{
    "txid": "12b8e7ede4992f4d30f93idj3085746951d945e39f40becebd7c290af8c2e7ad",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "mkrzDhhZtzQm8zgckSs4fMNrvtNJ66zaFe",
    "account": "micz",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a9143aa28e1740a6a5a2190975b6e7f1ad67aaec9a3988ac",
    "amount": 0.05000000,
    "confirmations": 94,
    "spendable": true
}, {
    "txid": "8443bc63b65d569ff9ekwm37sy3b67b9c7c6f8f386c3cdf372b260961b64ec9fc",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "mkrzDhhZtzQm8zgckSs4fMNrvtNJ66zaFe",
    "account": "micz",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a9143aa28e1740a6a5a2190975b6e7f1ad67aaec9a3988ac",
    "amount": 0.01000000,
    "confirmations": 93,
    "spendable": true
}]
```

> What we see here is the results that assigned 50 and 10 mBTC to our
>   address mkrz…. To spend this output, we will create a new transaction.

### **Step 2)**

`createrawtransaction`

> We need to choose some blocks with sufficient amount from the result of `listunspent`. Since we only need to send 0.02500000 mBTC I think the first block has enough amount to make the transaction.

*Format:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction
    '[{
        "txid" : "<txid_of_selected_block>",
        "vout" : <vout>
    }]'
    '{"<recipient_address>": <amount_to_send>, "<sender_address>": <amount_change>}'
```

> To pay the fee, we will reduce the change output by 0.5 millibits as
>   you can see below.

*Execute:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction
    '[{
        "txid" : "12b8e7ede4992f4d30f93idj3085746951d945e39f40becebd7c290af8c2e7ad",
        "vout" : 0
    }]'
    '{"mxh3H416KCRoBDiweSESew5YJyAk1nxLrN": 0.025, "mkrzDhhZtzQm8zgckSs4fMNrvtNJ66zaFe": 0.0245}'
```

*Result*

```
0100000001e34ac1e2baac09c366fce1c2245536bda8f7db0f6685862aecf53ebd69f9a89c0000000000ffffffff02a0252600000000001976a914d90d36e98f62968d2bc9bbd68107564a156a9bcf88ac50622500000000001976a91407bdb518fa2e6089fd810235cf1100c9c13d1fd288ac00000000
```

> The `createrawtransaction` command produces a raw hex string that
>   encodes the transaction details we supplied. If you want to decode the hex just use `decoderawtransaction` command.

### **Step 3)**

`signrawtransaction`

> signs the transaction in the serialized transaction format using
>   private keys stored in the wallet or provided in the call.

*Format:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction <hex_createrawtransaction>
```

*Execute:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction 0100000001e34ac1e2baac09c366fce1c2245536bda8f7db0f6685862aecf53ebd69f9a89c0000000000ffffffff02a0252600000000001976a914d90d36e98f62968d2bc9bbd68107564a156a9bcf88ac50622500000000001976a91407bdb518fa2e6089fd810235cf1100c9c13d1fd288ac00000000
```

*Result:*

```
{
   "hex" : "0100000001e34ac1e2baac09c366fce1c2245536bda8f7db0f6685862aecf53ebd69f9a89c000000006a47304402203e8a16522da80cef66bacfbc0c800c6d52c4a26d1d86a54e0a1b76d661f020c9022010397f00149f2a8fb2bc5bca52f2d7a7f87e3897a273ef54b277e4af52051a06012103c9700559f690c4a9182faa8bed88ad8a0c563777ac1d3f00fd44ea6c71dc5127ffffffff02a0252600000000001976a914d90d36e98f62968d2bc9bbd68107564a156a9bcf88ac50622500000000001976a91407bdb518fa2e6089fd810235cf1100c9c13d1fd288ac00000000",
   "complete" : true
}
```

> Now the `signrawtransaction` command returns another hex-encoded raw
>   transaction.

### **Step 4)**

`sendrawtransaction`

> RPC validates a transaction and broadcasts it to the peer-to-peer
>   network.

*Format:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction <hex_signrawtransaction>
```

*Execute:*

```
$ bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction 0100000001e34ac1e2baac09c366fce1c2245536bda8f7db0f6685862aecf53ebd69f9a89c000000006a47304402203e8a16522da80cef66bacfbc0c800c6d52c4a26d1d86a54e0a1b76d661f020c9022010397f00149f2a8fb2bc5bca52f2d7a7f87e3897a273ef54b277e4af52051a06012103c9700559f690c4a9182faa8bed88ad8a0c563777ac1d3f00fd44ea6c71dc5127ffffffff02a0252600000000001976a914d90d36e98f62968d2bc9bbd68107564a156a9bcf88ac50622500000000001976a91407bdb518fa2e6089fd810235cf1100c9c13d1fd288ac00000000
```

*Result:*

```
ae74538baa914f3799081ba78429d5d84f36a0127438e9f721dff584ac17b346
```

> The command `sendrawtransaction` returns a transaction hash (TXID) as it
>   submits the transaction on the network. To check the transaction hash, you can go to [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info) or [testnet.blockchain.info](http://testnet.blockchain.info) for Testnet network.